# Assign role to user in Scratch Org through sfdx command and send email notification to reset the password

Tags: salesforce, sfdx, salesforce-cli, salesforce-sfdx

I have to create users in scratch org through sfdx cli command and assign profile, role to the user.

The command used is

```
sfdx force:user:create -u <targetusername> -v <targetdevhubusername> Username=testuser1@my.org LastName=testuser1 Email=me@my.org profileName='System Administrator' generatepassword=true
```

But I want to assign role as well to the user.
Tried few ways like
Adding parameter to the user create command

```
UserRole='System Admin'
```

But its not working.

Can anybody please help me in assigning role to user through sfdx cli.

And once the user is created through Salesforce UI, we have button to *Reset Password* or checkbox to *Generate new password and notify user immediately*.

I want to do the same with sfdx cli.

Can anybody help me here. I am stuck since long time.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What does "It's not working" mean? Do you receive an error message? Is there actually a Role named "System Admin" in your org?

Comment: Yes I have a role named System Admin. There is no parameter I could foind in sfdx command to assign role to user.

Comment: Wow od you consider abandoning that command, writing user creation as Apex snippet and then sfdx force:apex:execute?

Comment: How can that be done. I tried executing
user.UserRoleId=[select Id from UserRole where Name = 'System Admin'].Id;
and run sfdx force:apex:execute, but it gave me error as 
Error: A value cannot be stored to UserRoleId in type User
I am very new to salesforce so facing difficulty here